# Need select list to display the value, not the text

Tags: jquery, select

http://jsbin.com/uluwum/3/edit

I have a select list of US states where I only want the two letter, abbreviated version to display by default and after a different state is selected. So it needs to display the selected value instead of the selected text when a select list is in its default state, but still display the option text when clicked on, but I can't figure out how to do that. I didn't think it was going to be a difficult thing to do, but either the searches that I've tried are so far off base that no relevant results were returned or this is an unusual request.

I put my extremely lame attempts in the above JSBin example all commented out.

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
        $('#states option').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('data-text', $(this).text());
            if($(this).is(':selected') == false)
            {
               $(this).text($(this).val());
            }        
        });

        $('select').on('change', function(){
            reset();
            var selected = $('option:selected');
            selected.text(selected.attr('data-text'));
        });

        function reset()
        {
          $('#states option').each(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).val());
          });  
        }
    });
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/2/

This should do what you want.

Comment: I don't think I explained this very well: I want it to do the exact opposite of the way your example works. It should display the abbreviated state name by default, but display the full state name when you click on the select list. That way I can make the select list width considerably smaller than it is now.

Comment: I dont think what your describing can be done without using a div container that simulates a drop down , then placing the :selected value on the option that it corresponds to, sort of like a lookup drop down...using an actual html drop down theres no data map to relate to

Comment: @David-Esteves - I made a change to your solution to fix my poor initial explanation and I got it to do the first part, which is setting the initial selection to the value instead of the text but I haven't figured out how to get the change event to do the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/4/ okay, after another attempt I was able to get it to use the selected value after the onchange event. The only thing that I can't figure out is how to get the reset() to change the currently selected entry back to the default before changing the new one. If anyone could fix that, I would be eternally grateful (well, maybe not _eternally_, but for quite a while at least...)

Comment: Success! http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/5/ I realized that the reason it wasn't resetting the state back to the original text was because it was lost once it was set to the value. D'oh! So I just created a variable to store the state name and then reset it when a new state was selected. This will be put to use in one of my latest projects later on today and should work out quite nicely. Thanks to David for doing all the heavy lifting on this, which then made it pretty easy to make it work the way I wanted it to originally.

Comment: Only thing i'd mention is after you select an item, it retains its abbreviation in the drop down rather than its full name, select Colorado, then go back into the list, you see that CO remains as a state name

Comment: Yeah, and although it's not ideal, I think that's something that I can live with. The full name does get restored if you select something else, however.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/6/ - Realized that I needed to set the variable again onchange, so I updated the file on JSFiddle. As a side note, I have a few forms where there is more than one state field and I'm having trouble putting another copy on the same page and getting them to function independently of one another. That may be a question for another time, however.

Answer (score 0):

This was about as close as I could get: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YbTgM/)**

```
$('select option').each(function() {
    $(this).data('abbr', $(this).val());
    $(this).data('full', $(this).text());
    $(this).text($(this).val());
});
$('select').change(function() {
    $('option:selected', this).text($('option:selected', this).data('full'));
    $('option:not(":selected")', this).each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).data('abbr'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please forgive my initial explanation, because it obviously wasn't clear enough: I want to retain the full state names in all but the selected option and then if another option is selected, that entry would display using the two letter abbreviation and the one that was previously selected needs to display the full name again. This is halfway there: http://jsfiddle.net/UMs98/3/ Thanks for taking the time to give it a shot, though. I totally appreciate the effort...